# COnflict in population of Jtable

Tags: java, swing

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try{
            String r1=rol1.getText();
            String sql="select * from parent where roll=?";
            pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1,r1);
            pst.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next())
            {

                report.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: And the question is...

Answer (score 0):

how can this even `compile` you havent even created a `resultset`, execute query 
and assign value to a `resultset` then populate the `jtable`

```
    resultSet rs =  pst.executeQuery();
    if(rs.next())
    {

        report.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    }
```

maybe you are `refferring to a another result set` variable then ofcource the values are conflicting.